# jquery json showing undefined with html table parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to show below json data on html table.how can i show to html table when i try to show with below code its show mae undefined

```
[
      {
        "Key": "data",
        "Value": [
          [
            {
              "Key": "created_time",
              "Value": "2020-09-27T21:38:10+0000"
            },
            {
              "Key": "message",
              "Value": "My message"
            },
            {
              "Key": "id",
              "Value": "116312453556631_122404992947377"
            }
          ]
      },
      {
        "Key": "paging",
        "Value": [
          {
            "Key": "cursors",
            "Value": [
              {
                "Key": "before",
                "Value": ""
              },
              {
                "Key": "after",
                "Value": ""
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Below is my Code and its show me undefined

```
                success: function (data) {
                    var items = '';
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        
                        var rows = "<tr>"
                        + "<td class='prtoducttd'>" + item.ID + "</td>"
                        + "<td class='prtoducttd'>" + item.Message + "</td>"
                        + "</tr>";
                        $('#tblPost tbody').append(rows);
                    });
                  
                }
```

what is generic method to parse the json and show it to html table?

**Out put**

```
id                                message        created_time
116312453556631_122404992947377  "My message" "2020-09-27T21:38:10+0000"
```

Comment: There are no `ID` or `Message` properties in the JSON. What are you expecting to be put into the table?

Comment: Your JSON is hierarchical. It's not obvious how to show that in a simple table.

Comment: @Barmar i just edited my question and i add expected out put

Answer (score 0):

Check if `item.Key == "data"`. If it is, loop through `item.Value` to get the values for that row.

```js
var data = [{
    "Key": "data",
    "Value": [{
        "Key": "created_time",
        "Value": "2020-09-27T21:38:10+0000"
      },
      {
        "Key": "message",
        "Value": "My message"
      },
      {
        "Key": "id",
        "Value": "116312453556631_122404992947377"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Key": "paging",
    "Value": [{
      "Key": "cursors",
      "Value": [{
          "Key": "before",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Key": "after",
          "Value": ""
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  if (item.Key == "data") {
    let id, message, created;
    $.each(item.Value, function(j, obj) {
      switch (obj.Key) {
        case 'id':
          id = obj.Value;
          break;
        case 'message':
          message = obj.Value;
          break;
        case 'created_time':
          created = obj.Value;
          break;
      }
    });
    debugger;
    let rows = "<tr>" +
      "<td class='prtoducttd'>" + id + "</td>" +
      "<td class='prtoducttd'>" + message + "</td>" +
      "<td class='prtoducttd'>" + created + "</td>" +
      "</tr>";
    $('#tblPost tbody').append(rows);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblPost">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Message</th>
      <th>Created Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've added an executable snippet. There were some mismatched brackets in the JSON, I had to fix them to get it running.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're getting the data correctly first

For example, at item[0] see if the scope chain shows object available.  Use the debugger and console to look through the data structure to follow the scope chain.  Then write a loop once you've got the item and i correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    for (i = 0; i < item.Value.length; i++) {

                        
                        let rows = "<tr>" +
                            "<td class='prtoducttd'>" + item.Value[i][2].Value + "</td>" +
                            "<td class='prtoducttd'>" + item.Value[i][1].Value + "</td>" +
                            "<td class='prtoducttd'>" + formatDate(new Date(item.Value[i][0].Value)) + "</td>" +
                            "</tr>";
                        $('#tblPost tbody').append(rows);

                    }
                });
```